# MySQL DATE_ADD?

Tags: mysql

01) I have a MySQL table named `issue`. It is storing book details as book_no, book_name, `is_date` etc.. issued for various members.

02) I need to select list of books that should return on current date. The return date is calculated by adding 3 days to the `is_date`. I used following script. But I returned an empty result.

**Variables used to Store return dates**

```
$rdate=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM issue"));
$is_date=$rdate['is_date'];

$rt_date=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT 
DATE_ADD('$is_date', INTERVAL 3 DAY) FROM dual"));
```

**SELECT statement**

```
SELECT issue.b_no, issue.b_name, issue.is_date 
FROM issue WHERE '$rt_date' = CURDATE()
```

03) I can not understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: your date format is ????

Comment: date format is yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: I think that your $rt_date is not just one value, so you should probably using a range selector.
What is the value of $rt_date?

Comment: Yes. Rik 22. It is an array. But I used another code to select relevant value from the array.